# What is the dimension of intersection of two polynomial subspaces of atmost degree 20 polynomial space?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let V = $P_{20}[\mathbb{R}]$ 
 
W = $\{p(x)\in V : p(1)=0, p(\frac{1}{2})=0, p(5)=0, p(7)=0\}$ 
 
U = $\{p(x)\in V :  p(\frac{1}{2})=0,p(3)=0, p(4)=0, p(7)=0\}$ 
Then what is the dimension of $W \cap U$?

My argument is, Each W and U are 17 (=21-4) dimensional subspaces. So $dim(W \cap U ) \leq 17$ and $W \cap U = \{p(x): p(\frac{1}{2})=0,p(1)=0,p(3)=0,p(4)=0, p(5)=0, p(7)=0,\}$ 
There are six independent conditions make $W \cap U$. so $dim(W \cap U)$ = 21-6 = 15.
**Is it Correct?** 
I am getting doubt since, $17\leq dim(W+U)\leq21$ and hence $13\leq dim(W \cap U) \leq 17$ this implies $dim(W+U) = 19$ (if my answer $dim(W \cap U))=15$ is correct) Is there any chance of getting other than 15 (between 13 and 17)?

Comment: Yes $\dim(W \cap U)= 15$ is correct